# Python fabric calling script "remote path"

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using fabric to connect to remote host, when i'm there, I try to call a script that I made (It parses the file I give in argument). But when I call the script from inside my Fabfile.py, it assumes the path I gave is from the machine I launch the fabfile from (so not my remote host)

In my fabfile.py I have:

```
Import import servclasse
env.host='host1'
def listconf():
  #here I browes to the correct folder
  s=servclasse.Server("my.file") #this is where I want it to open the host1:my.file file and instanciate a classe from what it parsed
```

If i do this, it tries to open the file from the folder where  servclass.py is. Is there a way to give a "remote path" in argument? I would rather not downloading the file. 
Should I upload the script servclasse.py with the `operation.put` before calling it?

---

Edit: more info
In my servclasse I have this:

```
def __init__(self, path):
    self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    self.config.readfp(open(path))
```

Comment: I tried to use the `fabric.contrib.files.append` function, to append to an empty file `run('cat my.file')`but i can't manage to make it work. Could this be a solution?

Comment: Please post the part of your external script (`servclasse.py`) related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `open()` was the problem.
I figured out how to do it so i'll drop it here in case someone read this topic one day :

```
def listconf():
 #first I browes to the correct folder then
    contents = StringIO.StringIO()
    get("MyFile",contents)
    contents.seek(0)
    s=Server(contents)
```

and in the servclass.py

```
def __init__(self, objfile):
    self.config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    self.config.readfp(objfile)
    #and i do my stuffs
```